# Tone js giving errors while trying to play a file on pc in main process of electron-react app

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-react-boilerplate, tonejs

I want to play audio files (mp3/wav) in my electron app, Right now I am using react as ui and sending ipcEvents back and forth between main process and renderer to try to play the audio file. I am using Tone js for doing so, below is the code where I've registered events for managing audio files.

```
import path from "path";
import fs from "fs";
import * as Tone from "tone";
import { IpcMain, IpcMainEvent } from "electron";
import { LOAD_LITE_AUDIO, PAUSE_LITE_AUDIO, PLAY_LITE_AUDIO, LITE_AUDIO_STATUS  } from "../../../../ipcEvents";

let player: Tone.Player | null;

const registerLiteAudioEvents = (ipcMain: IpcMain) => {
  ipcMain.on(LOAD_LITE_AUDIO, (event: IpcMainEvent, filePath) => {
    if (player) {
      player.stop();
      player.dispose();
      player = null;
    }

    const loadAudioFile = async () => {
      const audioFilePath = path.resolve(filePath);
      const fileExists = fs.existsSync(audioFilePath);

      if (fileExists) {
        const fileBuffer = fs.readFileSync(audioFilePath);
        const audioBuffer = await Tone.context.decodeAudioData(fileBuffer);

        player = new Tone.Player(audioBuffer).toDestination();
        // Start playing the audio
        event.reply(PLAY_LITE_AUDIO);
      } else {
        console.error("Audio file does not exist:", audioFilePath);
      }
    };

    (async () => {
      await loadAudioFile();
    })(); // IIFE
  });

  ipcMain.on(PLAY_LITE_AUDIO, (event: IpcMainEvent) => {
    if (player) {
      player.start();
      event.reply(LITE_AUDIO_STATUS, { isPlaying: true, initialVolume: 100 });
    }
  });

  ipcMain.on(PAUSE_LITE_AUDIO, (event: IpcMainEvent) => {
    if (player) {
      player.stop();
      event.reply(LITE_AUDIO_STATUS, { isPlaying: false, initialVolume: 100 });
    }
  });
};

export default registerLiteAudioEvents;
```

I've checked the imports and event firing already, events are being fired properly all imports are correct other than the `import Tone from "tone"` I'm not really sure about this one,
Below is the error I am getting

```
[8484:0629/162814.849:ERROR:CONSOLE(2)] "TypeError: object null is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))", source: node:electron/js2c/sandbox_bundle (2)
(node:8484) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: AudioBuffer is not defined
...at More lines // they didn't tell the problem so i removed em
(node:8484) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting 
a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
```

I'd like to know how can I make this work, over that I'm also down to know any other approach to play audio files with electron.